# Manage separate translation files (.po) in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, gettext

I am not an expert in `Python` or `gettext utilities`. I have a Django project in which I have several modules in the application. I need to maintain separate `.po` translation files for each module that will be merged in the time deployment. For instance, there is a `Dictionary` module beside the `django-cms-2` module for both of which I want to have different `.po` files (such as `dict.po` and `django-cms-master.po`). Then, I will use `msgmerge` and `compilemessages` from `gettext` and Django to create the final `django.mo` file. Is there any solution for what I need?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my quick hack to merge multiple .po-files under locale/LOCALE_CODE/ into locale/LOCALE_CODE/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# quick hack to merge all .po-files found under ./locale/LOCALE/
# to a django.po-file and then compile the django.po to django.mo

for l in locale/*
do
    bn=$(basename $l)
    echo "translating locale $bn"
    cat $l/*.po > $l/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
    python manage.py compilemessages -l $bn
done
```